# SignalR trace to file not working

Tags: configuration, iis-7.5, signalr, trace

I am trying to diagnose an intermittant fault with SignalR, so I want to enable tracing. I followed this guide

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

However it is not working or I cannot find the files which are being produced. The configuration in the example just lists the name of the file to log, but no path. 
Is there anything else I need to do to get this working? For examples any settings on IIS or additional configuration?
If it is working where would the files be written to?

I am using SignalR 2.1.2 and running it in IIS 7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set permissions on the folder the trace file was attempting to write to for the application pool the signalr service is running in. For example the user for the application pool is

```
IIS APPPOOL\<Application Pool Name>
```